# What CSS rules to display a background image without cutting off?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I know there are already a zillion questions and answers concerning CSS background-image, but I cannot find the proper answer, unfortunately; above that, some of the answers are quite old...

My CSS:

```
#showcase {
  min-height: 500px;
  background: url('../img/P1220784--grijs-1920.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #a21a21;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Almost perfect for me, except that, on resizing, the image gets cut off on the sides. The image is a photo of people, so I want all of them shown!
(I should have added that the image I use is 1920 * 798 pixels)
Can this be done?

Thank you,
Ad

Comment: `background-size: cover;` does that. It will cover the element. It depends how you want it to behave? Maybe it's better to use a img tag if you want to keep the aspect ratio so to speak?

Comment: @Dejan.S: your suggestion might be better. I'll have to experiment more, since there also should be some text inside the "showcase".

Comment: If keeping the aspect ratio is important then that is the approach to go. The text will probably be to large to fit in the image when its going down to mobile, but then you could just put the text below or above the image. That could eventually happen already at a tablet media query. It's a common approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have chosen to follow @Dejan.S' suggestion. The `img` as an HTML tag, and not use it as background. Makes my life a lot easier!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Okay, almost perfect. The photo is shown in full glory. Only: small screen displays a lot of white space around it! Maybe @media query to enhance this?

Comment: It is hard to avoid the white space. Other wise you have to adjust with cropping of the image or stretching the proportions.

|| background-size: 100% 100%;|| will give you uncropped image with out white space, but it can lost the proportions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size: auto 100%;`

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work; image still gets cut off on small screen, and full-screen it does not strech to full width!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try live all possible properties attributes of "background-size" in browser.

Background-size : 100% -Make Image cover whole div but Image will Stretched.

Background-size : coved - Make Image cover whole div with responsive cutoff functionality.

Background-size: auto/contain - Set Image responsibly according to height width on div but not cover whole.